# Django architecture with interactive models

Tags: django, architecture, data-modeling

I am trying to develop a book-keepign web app based on Django.  I am trying to use a double entry accounting system, so my models are:

- Account

  - name
  - date_created
  - owner
  - opening_balance
  - reconciled_balance
- FullTransaction

  - date
  - memo
  - check_no
- HalfTransaction

  - ForeignKey(FullTransaction)
  - amount
  - debit_flag
  - current_balance
  - reconciled_flag

My question is multipart:  Where does the business logic that saves FullTransaction and HalfTransaction belon since the FullTransaction and HalfTransactions need to be saved atomically (or should the architecture be different?).  The django tutorial does not have much business logic to address these kinds of issues, and I'm not sure overriding the save method to save other objects is right.

Also, is it inappropriate for the balance to be stored as part of the transaction, as it requires an update of all newer transactions if an old one is edited or inserted?

Answer (score -1):

> Where does the business logic that saves FullTransaction and HalfTransaction belong?

In an application.

> The FullTransaction and HalfTransactions need to be saved atomically (should the architecture be different?).

Is this a question?

> Also, is it inappropriate for the balance to be stored as part of the transaction, as it requires an update of all newer transactions if an old one is edited or inserted?

It depends on performance requirements.

For speed, pre-aggregated data is important.

For simplicity, atomic data is important.  In this case, you must recompute aggregates.

Since you didn't provide performance information, it's impossible to tell if it's appropriate or inappropriate.